# React-native problem with launching the app

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

So the give brief summary of my problem: In my team, I have already once succesfully set up the project and I contributed some code. But after some commits from other users, and my pull, the whole thing broke. I have tried doing almost everything: from deleting app, reinstalling visual code, cloning a new project, trying a new emulator, updating my apk and sdk but nothing helped. Can somebody guide me to solution? As I said it worked once before, and that is why I find it weird. Thanks!

```
PS C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013> npx react-native  run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1177 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
06:04:18 V/EmulatorConsole: Creating emulator console for 5554
06:04:18 V/EmulatorConsole: Removing emulator console for 5554
06:04:18 V/ddms: execute: running getprop
06:04:18 V/ddms: execute 'getprop' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
06:04:18 V/ddms: execute: returning
06:04:20 V/EmulatorConsole: Creating emulator console for 5554
06:04:20 V/EmulatorConsole: Removing emulator console for 5554
06:04:20 V/ddms: execute: running getprop
06:04:20 V/ddms: execute 'getprop' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
06:04:20 V/ddms: execute: returning

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 26.0.0
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 18.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 10.1.0 (10,1,0 - 10001000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 16
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 26.0.0
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 10.1.0 (10,1,0 - 10001000)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 16
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :app:installDebug
06:04:55 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
06:04:55 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
06:04:55 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_3a_API_30(AVD) - 11' for app:debug
06:04:55 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
06:04:55 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
06:04:55 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
06:04:55 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
06:05:00 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
06:05:00 V/ddms: execute: returning

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
200 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 198 up-to-date
Unable to install C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/~~Rx5duZGr2ho38Sk1bydg6w==/com.mrent-oCRjx4p_5Ced7xi8LUcT2A==/base.apk code is missing
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1133)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:963)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:939)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:928)
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:126)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:175)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.doTaskAction(InstallVariantTask.java:106)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:727)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/~~Rx5duZGr2ho38Sk1bydg6w==/com.mrent-oCRjx4p_5Ced7xi8LUcT2A==/base.apk 
code is missing

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Unable to install C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "react-native "run-android""

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sven\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-23T17_05_02_796Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013>
```

Comment: problem is not in your pc, the problem is on your mobile, `:app:installDebug FAILED` installDebug failed comes when you don't give the permission to install your application on your phone or emulator

Comment: So how do I give the permission ?

Comment: open system settings and enable usb install option

Comment: I did that, and I restarted my PC. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE]: I did the following steps:

1)cd android in terminal
2)gradlew clean
cd ..
3)react-native run-android

Now i got following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013> npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1114 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 26.0.0
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 18.1.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 10.1.0 (10,1,0 - 10001000)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 16
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 26.0.0
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 10.1.0 (10,1,0 - 10001000)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 29
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 16
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\react-native\android

> Task :react-native-community_google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-firebase_app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
158 actionable tasks: 155 executed, 3 up-to-date
Note: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-community\google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\auth\ReactNativeFirebaseAuthModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\reanimated\NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\android\app\src\debug\java\com\mrent\ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\android\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:518)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingParams.getAllDexFiles(DexMergingTask.kt:502)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:423)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:198)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\android\app\build\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013\node_modules\@react-native-community\google-signin\android\src\main\java\co\apptailor\googlesignin\RNGoogleSigninModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.       
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Sven\Desktop\FAKS\MRENT projekt\AIR2013
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "react-native "run-android""

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sven\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-24T18_31_11_425Z-debug.log
```